# Html / Javascript - Div Showing & Hiding

Tags: javascript, html, hide

Little Layout
MDIV
ADIV = BDIV

I'm trying to hide and show divs with onclicks and failing miserably.

When function MA() button is clicked = ADIV to show and BDIV to hide

When function MB() button is clicked = BDIV to show and ADIV to hide

```js
function MA() {

  document.getElementById("ADIV").style.display = "";
  document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "none";


}

function MB() {

  document.getElementById("ADIV").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "";


}
```

```html
<div id="MDIV">
  <button onclick="MA()">MA</button>
  <button onclick="MB()">MB</button>
</div>


<div id="ADIV">
  <button onclick="A()">ADIV</button>
</div>
<div id="BDIV">
  <button onclick="B()">BDIV</button>
</div>
```

Sidenote
Also if anyone can explain how to load with just MDIV - ADIV on page load.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Your code works exactly as you specified it should - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: ohman...

runs palms across face slowly
just one of those days man cheers for pointing that out i edited it for the post

the small detail i changed made it work 
i had
    document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "show";
but i woked it out somewhere when i asked the question
    document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "";

Comment: You say you are "failing miserably", how so?  What are you seeing that you shouldn't?  What isn't happening but should?  Try to be specific.

Comment: rather new to it all so i spend more time researching how to do it rather than doing it 

i was trying somewhat to be able to hide divs and get them up again and i got deeper into google than google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already toggles the visibility of the two elements on click of the respective buttons. However, you'll probably want to turn your elements to `style.display = block` when they're visible, rather than just removing the `display` style entirely.

In order to have `#BDIV` hidden by default, simply run 
`document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "none";` outside of your two functions.

This can be seen in the following example:

```js
document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "none";

function MA() {
  document.getElementById("ADIV").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "none";
}

function MB() {
  document.getElementById("ADIV").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="MDIV">
    <button onclick="MA()">MA</button>
    <button onclick="MB()">MB</button>
  </div>
  <div id="ADIV">
    <button onclick="A()">ADIV</button>
  </div>
  <div id="BDIV">
    <button onclick="B()">BDIV</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks helped a bunch got the part i was working on doing what it needed too

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the sidenote: you should provide a default style of `display: none` for that BDIV:

```js
function MA() {

  document.getElementById("ADIV").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "none";


}

function MB() {

  document.getElementById("ADIV").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("BDIV").style.display = "block";


}
```

```html
<div id="MDIV">
  <button onclick="MA()">MA</button>
  <button onclick="MB()">MB</button>
</div>


<div id="ADIV">
  <button onclick="A()">ADIV</button>
</div>
<div id="BDIV" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="B()">BDIV</button>
</div>
```

**Edit**: I would recommend explicitly setting a value for the `display`-property. Either use `inline`, `block`, or `inline-block`, depending on what you need.

Comment: how would I determine what I need?

Comment: that was pretty vaque questioning what does each one do?

Comment: The proper explanation could fill a page, but in essence, `block` creates line-breaks before and after the element and allows it to have properties like `width` and `height`, whereas `inline` fits itself into the "flow" of text/other elements. And `inline-block` is when you need both ;-) There is a brief wrap-up [here](http://learnlayout.com/display.html) as well as [on the almighty CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/).

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden style or CSS to the elements you want hidden on page load.  I have added inline styling here to hide "BDIV".

Don't use JavaScript for styling on page load unless you have to.  It is better to use CSS or styling.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="MDIV">
    <button onclick="MA()">MA</button>
    <button onclick="MB()">MB</button>
</div>                

<div id="ADIV">
    <button onclick="A()">ADIV</button>
</div>

<div id="BDIV" style="display: none;">
    <button onclick="B()">BDIV</button>
</div>

</body>
</html> 

<script>
//CACHE YOUR ELEMENTS

var mdiv = document.getElementById('MDIV');
var adiv = document.getElementById('ADIV');
var bdiv = document.getElementById('BDIV');

//helper functions
function hide(elm) { elm.style.display = 'none'; }
function show(elm) { elm.style.display = 'block'; }

function MA() {
  hide(adiv);
  show(bdiv);
}

function MB() {
  hide(adiv);
  show(bdiv);
}


</script>
```